# render the last days of the previous month within a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to render the last few days from the last month, however, the days are not rendering in the proper squares. Ideally Tuesday should be the 31st, Monday should be the 30th, and so on.

How could I go about making such changes that reflects the correct days in the respective squares?

*(click to enlarge)*

[image]

**Code Snippet**

```js
let nav = 0;

const getCalendar = document.getElementById("calendar");

const weekDays = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
];

function nextButton() {
  document.getElementById("nextButton")?.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav++;
    render();
  });
}

function backButton() {
  document.getElementById("backButton")?.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav--;
    render();
  });
}

function render() {
  const dt = new Date();

  if (nav !== 0) {
    dt.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + nav);
  }

  const day = dt.getDate();
  const month = dt.getMonth();
  const year = dt.getFullYear();
  const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 1);
  const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();

  const lastDateOfLastMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

  const dateString = firstDayOfMonth.toLocaleString("en-us", {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
  });

  const getFirstDayMonth = dateString.split(", ")[0]; // Wednesday
  const days = weekDays.indexOf(getFirstDayMonth);

  (
    document.getElementById("month-heading")
  ).innerText = 
  `${dt.toLocaleDateString("en-us", { month: "long" })} ${year}`;
  
  getCalendar.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 1; i <= days + daysInMonth; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.classList.add("day");

    const addedDay = i - days;

    /**
     * if the index is greater than the first day of the month add text for numbers
     *
     * else add padding squares
     */

    if (i > days) {
      square.innerText = addedDay;

      if (addedDay === day && nav === 0) {
        square.id = "currentDay";
      }
    } else {


      // enter the last few days of last month here this is where i might be doing 
      // something wrong 


      square.innerText = lastDateOfLastMonth - i + 1;

      // square.classList.add("padding");
    }
    getCalendar?.appendChild(square);
  }
}

nextButton();
backButton();

render();
```

```css
/* CSS may differ from original */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#header {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
#weekdays, #calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 6rem [col-start]);
}
.day, #weekdays > div {
  width: 6rem;
}
#weekdays > div {
  border-bottom: thin solid gray;
  border-top: thin solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.day {
  border: thin solid gray;
  height: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calendar-body">
    <div id="header">
      <h1 id="month-heading"></h1>
      <div>
        <button id="backButton">Back</button>
        <button id="nextButton">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="weekdays">
      <div>Sunday</div>
      <div>Monday</div>
      <div>Tuesday</div>
      <div>Wednesday</div>
      <div>Thursday</div>
      <div>Friday</div>
      <div>Saturday</div>
    </div>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the assignment:

```
square.innerText = lastDateOfLastMonth - i + 1;
```

by

```
square.innerText = lastDateOfLastMonth - days + i;
```